# how can I host my django app on Godaddy dedicated server (delux)?

Tags: django, heroku, hosting

I Have no idea how to set things up on this fresh centOS 7 server, how to host my django app with postgre db in this server?

Comment: I believe you have a control panel. kindly login to it to host your application from it.  The control panel has all the options to host your application.

Comment: no.. i dont see options to config a python app in there